# check if new table exists in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to check dynamically,

- if new table exists, then I want to retrieve the data from the new table and insert those values to another table.
- if new table does not exist, then I want to print no new table exists.

The table is AAA_AAA,

| emp_id | emp_name | emp_salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | abc | 50000 |
| 121 | bcd | 45000 |

If new table exists then I have to select the values from the above table and insert those values into other table.

If new table does not exist then I want to print no new table exists.

I have written the query below,

```
select object_name from user_objects , case when select object_name from user_objects where created >= (sysdate-12/24) then select * from AAA_AAA into BBB_BBB;
```

BBB_BBB is the table name where I have to insert the values from AAA_AAA table if newly created table exists.

But I am not getting desired output.

Comment: This smacks of a seriously bad design.  Apart from code, how do you logically determine that a 'new' table exists? How long will this 'new' table be considered 'new'?  Will there be still more, newer 'new' tables in the future? What business purpose does this new table serve?  From your description of its use, it sounds like it is simply an entry point for loading data to a final destination. So where does the data for this 'new' table come from?  I _strongly_ suspect there is a better approach.

Comment: There will be some more tables. Every 30 minutes new tables will be created

Comment: _"Every 30 minutes new tables will be created"_  What about the rest of the questions?  This is sounding more and more like the entire design needs a re-think.

Comment: You should not be creating new tables "every 30 minutes".  Not even every month.  Sounds like you have a file of new data every 30 minutes that you are trying to get loaded into the "old" table.  For this you should be using a single external table, for which the data file is replaced as needed, or use sqlldr.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, one is as follows:

```
select table_name from user_tables where table_name='MYTABLE';
```

Then if the above works, then do the insertion with a backbend language like `PHP` or `C#` counting the table no.

```
if(result.Count() > 0)
{
   //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need dynamic SQL because - if table doesn't exist - code will fail.

Sample table (`aaa`), while `bbb` doesn't exist:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> select * from aaa;

    EMP_ID EMP EMP_SALARY
---------- --- ----------
       120 abc      50000
       121 bcd      45000

SQL> select * from bbb;
select * from bbb
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Code that does the job:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    select count(*)
  5      into l_cnt
  6      from user_tables
  7      where table_name = 'BBB';
  8
  9    if l_cnt = 0 then
 10       dbms_output.put_line('Table BBB does not exist');
 11    else
 12      execute immediate 'insert into bbb (emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary)' ||
 13        ' select emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary from aaa';
 14      dbms_output.put_line('Table AAA copied to table BBB');
 15    end if;
 16  end;
 17  /
Table BBB does not exist                      --> exactly, it doesn't exist

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

Let's create an empty target `bbb` table and repeat that code:

```
SQL> create table bbb as select * From aaa where 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL> select * from bbb;

no rows selected

SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    select count(*)
  5      into l_cnt
  6      from user_tables
  7      where table_name = 'BBB';
  8
  9    if l_cnt = 0 then
 10       dbms_output.put_line('Table BBB does not exist');
 11    else
 12      execute immediate 'insert into bbb (emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary)' ||
 13        ' select emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary from aaa';
 14      dbms_output.put_line('Table AAA copied to table BBB');
 15    end if;
 16  end;
 17  /
Table AAA copied to table BBB                        --> target table now exists

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from bbb;

    EMP_ID EMP EMP_SALARY
---------- --- ----------
       120 abc      50000                           --> here's its contents
       121 bcd      45000

SQL>
```